# A warning message “No matching signal for”

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, ros, vlc-qt

I'm using `qt-ros` based on `qt4` to build applications.

But there is a problem that `signal & slot` does not work.

The vlc-qt library I'm using provides a signal function called played, as shown in the link below.
[vlc-qt](https://vlc-qt.tano.si/reference/git/classVlcMediaListPlayer.html)

I try to connect to the `QMetaObject :: connectSlotsByName` method by creating the appropriate `slot` function, but it does not work with the warning "No matching signal for".

in mainWindow.h

```
public Q_SLOTS:
    void on_vListPlayer_played();
```

and in mainWindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_vListPlayer_played()
{
    ROS_INFO("player started!------------------------------");
}
...
MainWindow::MainWindow(int argc, char** argv, QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, qnode(argc,argv)
{
    ui.setupUi(this); // Calling this incidentally connects all ui's triggers to on_...() callbacks in this class.

    // UI Init
    QWidget* mainWidget = new QWidget(this);
    this->setCentralWidget(mainWidget);
    mainWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: black;");
    QVBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->setMargin(0);
    mainLayout->setSpacing(0);
    mainWidget->setLayout(mainLayout);

    m_vVideoWidget = new VlcWidgetVideo;
    mainLayout->addWidget(m_vVideoWidget);

    m_vInstance = new VlcInstance(VlcCommon::args(), this);
    m_vPlayer = new VlcMediaPlayer(m_vInstance);
    m_vPlayer->setVideoWidget(m_vVideoWidget);

    vListPlayer = new VlcMediaListPlayer(m_vPlayer, m_vInstance);
    QObject::connect(vListPlayer, SIGNAL(played()), this, SLOT(on_vListPlayer_played()));

    m_vVideoWidget->setMediaPlayer(m_vPlayer);

    m_vList = new VlcMediaList(m_vInstance);
    openVideoes(m_DataPath);

    vListPlayer->setMediaList(m_vList);
    vListPlayer->setPlaybackMode(Vlc::PlaybackMode::Repeat);

    vListPlayer->mediaPlayer()->play();
...
}
```

in MediaListPlayer.h (vlc-qt lib)

```
class VLCQT_CORE_EXPORT VlcMediaListPlayer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
......
public Q_SLOTS:
    void itemAt(int index);
    void next();
    void play();
    void previous();
    void stop();

Q_SIGNALS:

    void played();
    void nextItemSet(VlcMedia *media);
    void nextItemSet(libvlc_media_t *media);
    void stopped();
```

Comment: What's the complete warning message?

Comment: Did you update the moc files? What happens if you run qmake again, then (re)build?

Comment: @FrederikDeRuyck I do not know how to run qmake independently .I just use qt-ros / qt_build. "https://github.com/stonier/qt_ros/tree/indigo/qt_build"

Comment: @vahancho QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_vListPlayer_played()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Qt Designer, the generated code (that is called by `ui.setupUi(this);`) makes a call to `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(QObject *object)`.

As per [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName) this attempts to connect all slots with a name matching the following pattern: `void on_<object name>_<signal name>(<signal parameters>);`

As the slot `void on_vListPlayer_played()` matches the pattern, an attempt to connect it is made. But fails because you do not have any object [named](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop) `vListPlayer`.

In your case I would suggest you rename your slots so that they do not match the pattern and do not get connected automatically.